# Compressing logs everyday

Tags: linux, bash

I'm struggling with compressing my logs. I have a simple script which runs everynight

```
find /directory/logs -type f -mmin +1440 -print -exec gzip {} \;
```

But sometimes it skips my logs with different ending than *.log. For example it don't compress logs with *.log.1 *.log.0.lck etc.

Any ideas?

Comment: from the command all the files for which last modification time is more than 1440min (or 24 hours : 1440=24*60) are compressed

Comment: Did you consider using [logrotate](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate)?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you just don't use correctly the find command.

-mmin +1440 - find all files except last 1440min (24 hours)

-mmin -1440 or -mmin 1440 - find all files created in last 1440min (24 hours)

You can use "-mtime n", from man:
    **File's data was last modified n*24 hours ago. See the comments for -atime to understand how rounding affects the interpretation of file modification times.**

So for you:
find /directory/logs -type f **-mtime 1** -print -exec gzip {} \;